# How to read an xml file in flex actionscript 3

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I want to read an xml file placed in the same folder as the swf. Note however there is no webserver running.

```
<![CDATA[               

            private var my_req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("assets/GmetadOutput.xml");
            private var loader:URLLoader;   

            public function startup():void {
            output.text="CheckPoint1"; //This is the only output that displays!
  loader = new URLLoader(my_req);
  output.text="CheckPoint2";
  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,eventhandler);
  output.text="CheckPoint3";

  }

  public function eventhandler(ev:Event):void {
  output.text="CheckPoint4";
  output.text= XML(loader.data).string;
  }
        ]]>
```

So on the on CreationComplete event i call startup();
The Checkpoint1 output displays but none of the other checkpoints are reached?

Can anyone tell me what iam doing wrong or better yet tell me how to read a file placed in the same folder as the swf file!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's not reaching the second checkpoint... If you comment out `loader = new URLLoader(my_req);`, does it work?  If not, that's weird.

If you want to load local files in Flex, you sometimes have to set the `use-network=false` compiler argument (set it to false, it defaults to true).  Here's some info on [`use-network` and security sandboxes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05B_Security_04.html).

Let me know if that helps,
Lance

Comment: Hmm the '-use-network=false' did not help but what it did do was get me past loader = new URLLoader(my_req);

So now i get all the check points printed out.

However the output.text+= XML(loader.data).string+"\n"; outputs a blank line. Which means what?

I guess since its in the event.Complete that means the file was found and read? So now the question is why does it output a blank line.

Comment: Ha. Figured it out. 

output.text= XML(loader.data).string; 

The above line does not work.

Replaced it with 

output.text=loader.data;

and now i get the xml text!

Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'no webserver running' - I assume you saying that you are running it from a local file? In that case - you should use Adobe Air instead of just Flex - then it will work fine for you.

Comment: hmm thanks, lemme look into air. Is there no way to do it from flex?

Comment: Air and Flex are really the same thing - just a difference in how you deploy them. Flex swf files are not meant for desktop deployment.